# Fazer um GET do banco a partir de um Array Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, get, repository

Eu tenho um select onde faço uma busca a partir de um id informado,
No postman faco a um POST
mandando um array no como no exemplo abaixo

```
[
{  
      "id":"1"
},
{  
      "id":"2"
}
]
```

No repositório faço a busca desses id para poder obter todas as informações sobre eles.

como ficaria no meu repositório na hora de fazer a busca e trazer as informações dos ids informados atualmente eu faço uma busca simples com um get();

Repository:

```
Public function listarId($id)
    {
    return $this->produto = DB::table('produtos')
    ->where('id', $id)
    ->get();  
     }
```

e mando como paramentro no postman um id de cada vez

```
  {  
  "id":"2"
  }
```

no meu controller atualmente esta da seguinte maneira, eu mando request com a variavel $id, e retorno a select que fiz no repository.

```
   public function lista(Request $request) 
    {      

        $id = $request->input('id');

        return $this->produtosRepository->listarId($id);
    }
```

e eu quero poder mandar um array com varios ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você em vez de usar o where(); poderia utilizar o [whereIn();](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#where-clauses)

Por exemplo:

```
 return $this->produto = DB::table('produtos')
->where('id_admin', $array_id)
->get();
```

Aonde esse `$array_id` seria um array de id's.

> OBS.: o whereIn necessariamente precisa receber um array
>   unidimensional por exemplo `[1,2,3]`

Com isso ele va fazer uma query parecida com :

```
Select * from produtos where id_admin in (1,2);
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: No controllador eu envio eu tenho um Request onde passo o parâmetro id para fazer esta busca, porem retorna null, quando envio dessa maneira [
{  
      "id":"1"
},
{  
      "id":"2"
}
]      tem alguma maneira para conseguir pegar as informaçoes dessa array para fazer a busca

Comment: o id que passa é gerado aqui `$idP = $this->produtosRepository->lista($id);`?

Comment: sim, em teria sim, porem se eu envio como um array com mais de dois $id para fazer a busca no banco, retorna nulo, porem se envio apenas um {"id" : "5"} ele reconhece normalmente

Comment: Sim eu tenho que entender como você pega esses valores, quando usar o WhereIn você precisa passar o array simples por exemplo: `whereIn('id', [1,2,3]);`

Comment: bom editei a pergunta acho que agora da para compreender melhor

Comment: no caso o array de id que tu vai usar no where vem desse `lista()`? caso sim roda um dd(); para eu ver como está saindo essas informações, caso não da onde vem esses id's da busca

Comment: O id vem dessa variavel  $idarray = $request->input('id');
que eu passa como paramentro aqui $this ->produtosRepository->listarId($idarray );   quando mando apenas um id, da certo, porem mais de um ja retorna  null

Comment: @JessM roda um `dd();` nesse return pra eu entender melhor o que está passando

Comment: dd()  ta retornando [ ] vazio

Comment: se o dd(); está retornando null o problema está nos id's, ou melhor como você está recebendo eles,

Comment: sim , quando mando no postman {"id":"1"} ele retorna os valores corretamente, porem quando eu envio [{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"}] ele retorna vazio

Comment: [{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"}] isso você está mandando dentro do WhereIn ? se for ta manano um vetor bidimensional você tem que passar apenas os ids, ão precisa definir que está passando o id